# Failed to generate mapped ethash cache - Operation not supported

Tags: go-ethereum, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I'm setting up my ethereum node to eventually be a validator. I've been working to get the blockchain synced and things are running right now, but I see the error:

"Failed to generated mapped ethash cache - Operation not supported"

in the running event log. So far, it doesn't seem to affect the progress, but the error is generated every time there's a new epoch.

The research that I have done seems to indicate that ethash is for mining, which I won't be doing. Does this mean that I don't have to worry about these errors?